# utility type for JSON version of an existing type? JSON<SomeExistingType>

Tags: json, typescript

any utility type exist that would do this?

```js
const foo: Foo = { ... }
const bar: string = JSON.stringify(foo)
const baz: JSON<Foo> = JSON.parse(foo)
```

`JSON<Foo>` would have all the same properties as `Foo`, but with all the [changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) that `JSON.stringify` does

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is pretty much what i was looking for
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897

```js
type Json =
  | null
  | boolean
  | number
  | string
  | Json[]
  | { [prop: string]: Json };

type JsonCompatible<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Json
    ? T[P]
    : Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>>
    ? never
    : T[P] extends (() => any) | undefined
    ? never
    : JsonCompatible<T[P]>;
};
```